# How do you enable the spell check on outlook?

Tags: outlook.com

Since my hotmail account became Outlook, I've been unable to spell check my emails before sending them out. There's no spell check option on at the top of my email and there's no option spell check. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a browser that has a built-in spell check? Outlook.com doesn't show the spell check option if you do.

I just tested this by composing a message with both Firefox (which has a built-in spell checker) and Internet Explorer (which does not). In the latter, I see an option for "Spell Check" above the compose window between "Save draft" and "Options". On Firefox, I don't see the option (and my misspellings have red wavy underlines.)